# Why doesn't my s-log3 footage reach 100% value?

Tags: video, color-grading

Why does my footage captured with s-log3 gamma curve on a Sony FS5 seems to clip before 100% if I see it on a waveform? [image]

Answer (score 2):

A log curve is a mathematical transfer function.  SONY have defined a LOG curve (as many vendors do) that imagines future/alternative sensors having larger electron well capacity (higher clipping) and lower noise (lower clipping) than your current silicon design supports. In other words, you are seeing where your sensor's designs fits into an idealized LOG space.  You are not seeing a LOG curve that is limited by only what your particular sensor can achieve at the present moment.

Comment: Isn't that a waste of bits of data? Can I do something about it?

Comment: Panasonic's VLOG-L is a much larger waste of bits of data ;-)  But to answer your question: not unless and until SONY offers a RAW codec for your particular camera.